# Proof by induction, inductive step built from hypothesis

Tags: proof-writing

Suppose we are trying to prove some $P(n)$ by using proof by induction

First we show that $P(0)$ is true

Then we assume that $P(n-1)$ is true

In practically every math proof I have seen, in the inductive step we start with $P(n)$ and break it into $P(n-1)$ plus something else to show $P(n)$ is true

My question is, can we work forwards? i.e., in my inductive step can I say that it is true for $P(n-1)$, then we "build something up" to show that this $P(n-1)$ plus "something else" is true and that this is really $P(n)$?

If that doesn't make sense, here is a specific example:

i.e. if I am trying to prove some property of a graph in my inductive step, can I start from some $n-1$ verticy graph (my hypothesis) and say that we can add nodes/edges to make it a graph with $n$ verticies, then prove that this graph we can build satisfies the proof?

Comment: Working forwards is perfectly fine. I went in this direction when [I proved a number-theoretical statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964834/prove-that-every-positive-integer-having-3m-equal-digits-is-divisible-by-3m/1964874#1964874) here some time back.

Comment: Sure.  That (so far as I can understand your example ) is just fine.