# If $a$ is odd then $a^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod{2^{n+2}}$ for all $n≥1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $a$ is odd then $a^{2n} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{n+2}}$ for all $n≥1$

I try using induction but I'm not get it.Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you mean $a^{2^n}$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure. If it is $a^{2^n}$ , It is true?

Comment: @TheetaNonatee Yes.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147520/show-that-52e-2mod2e-1-mod2e

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Take $a=3, n=3$. Note that $$3^{6}=729 \equiv 25 \not \equiv 1 \pmod {2^{5}}$$
And $2^{5}=32$. Thus your claim is false.

Perhaps you mean $$a^{2^{n}}$$ in which case it follows from Euler's Formula and the fact that $$x^2+1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod {8}$$

Comment: Right. You beat me to it in correcting what the statement should have been.